# Creating a ColumnTransformer pipeline with user defined functions

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I´m trying to create a `ColumnTransformer` pipeline to then pass on a general processing pipeline and it will be mainly used to scale specific columns and add new columns to the data (like cube, etc)

I was trying this

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def take_cube(data,col):
    data["speed_cube"] = np.power(col,3)
    return data

def sin_angle(data, speed, acc):
    data["angle"] = data[speed] * np.sin(data[acc])
    
    return data

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("cube", FunctionTransformer(take_cube, validate=False), [speed]),
        ("sin_angle", FunctionTransformer(sin_angle, kw_args={"speed":"speed","acc":"acceleration"},validate=False), [speed, acceleration]),
    ],
    remainder="passthrough"
).set_output(transform="pandas")
```

But I'm not entirely sure how to format the column transformer in the format that is on sickit-learn (name, transformer, columns).

I'm supposedly already passing the columns I want to create the new columns as the kw_args in FunctionTransformer, and if I pass the list like ["speed,"acceleration"] it will create a bunch of extra columns that I don't want giving the following output:

```
                     cube__speed  sin_angle__speed  sin_angle__acceleration  \
                                                                              
2020-08-18 14:43:19    80.901828             4.325                   0.0880   
2020-08-18 14:43:20    81.520685             4.336                   0.0842   
2020-08-18 14:43:21    85.707790             4.409                   0.0234   
2020-08-18 14:43:22    87.824421             4.445                   0.0016   
2020-08-18 14:43:23    87.587538             4.441                   0.1144   
...                          ...               ...                      ...   
2020-09-13 14:55:57     1.170905             1.054                   0.0234   
2020-09-13 14:55:58     0.569723             0.829                   0.0258   
2020-09-13 14:55:59     0.233745             0.616                  -0.1686   
2020-09-13 14:56:00     0.000000             0.000                  -0.4284   
2020-09-13 14:56:01     0.000000             0.000                  -0.3096   

                     sin_angle__speed_ang  remainder__heart-rate  \
                                                                   
2020-08-18 14:43:19              0.380109                  102.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:20              0.364660                  103.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:21              0.103161                  105.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:22              0.007112                  106.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:23              0.506943                  106.0   
...                                   ...                    ...   
2020-09-13 14:55:57              0.024661                  130.0   
2020-09-13 14:55:58              0.021386                  130.0   
2020-09-13 14:55:59             -0.103366                  129.0   
2020-09-13 14:56:00             -0.000000                  130.0   
2020-09-13 14:56:01             -0.000000                  130.0   

                     remainder__cadence  remainder__slope  remainder__angle  
                                                                             
2020-08-18 14:43:19                64.0         -0.033870         -0.033857  
2020-08-18 14:43:20                64.0         -0.033571         -0.033559  
2020-08-18 14:43:21                66.0         -0.033223         -0.033210  
2020-08-18 14:43:22                66.0         -0.032908         -0.032896  
2020-08-18 14:43:23                67.0          0.000000          0.000000  
...                                 ...               ...               ...  
2020-09-13 14:55:57                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:55:58                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:55:59                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:56:00                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:56:01                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000
```

What changes would I need to make so that I can make the `ColumnTransformer` user-defined functions take in the kw_args and create the extra columns as intended?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay this seems to kinda work, but I still would like to have better column names:

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def take_cube(data, col):
    data["speed_cube"] = np.power(data[col], 3)
    return data[['speed_cube']]

def sin_angle(data, speed, acc):
    data["angle"] = data[speed] * np.sin(data[acc])
    return data[['angle']]

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ("step1", FunctionTransformer(take_cube, kw_args={'col': 'speed'}, validate=False), ['speed']),
        ("step2", FunctionTransformer(sin_angle, kw_args={'speed': 'speed', 'acc': 'acceleration'}, validate=False), ['speed', 'acceleration']),
    ],
    remainder="passthrough"
).set_output(transform="pandas")
new_data = preprocessor.fit_transform(data)

print(new_data)
```

Output:

````
                   step1__speed_cube  step2__angle  remainder__heart-rate  \
                                                                              
2020-08-18 14:43:19          80.901828      0.380109                  102.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:20          81.520685      0.364660                  103.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:21          85.707790      0.103161                  105.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:22          87.824421      0.007112                  106.0   
2020-08-18 14:43:23          87.587538      0.506943                  106.0   
...                                ...           ...                    ...   
2020-09-13 14:55:57           1.170905      0.024661                  130.0   
2020-09-13 14:55:58           0.569723      0.021386                  130.0   
2020-09-13 14:55:59           0.233745     -0.103366                  129.0   
2020-09-13 14:56:00           0.000000     -0.000000                  130.0   
2020-09-13 14:56:01           0.000000     -0.000000                  130.0   

                     remainder__cadence  remainder__slope  remainder__angle  
                                                                             
2020-08-18 14:43:19                64.0         -0.033870         -0.033857  
2020-08-18 14:43:20                64.0         -0.033571         -0.033559  
2020-08-18 14:43:21                66.0         -0.033223         -0.033210  
2020-08-18 14:43:22                66.0         -0.032908         -0.032896  
2020-08-18 14:43:23                67.0          0.000000          0.000000  
...                                 ...               ...               ...  
2020-09-13 14:55:57                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:55:58                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:55:59                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:56:00                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  
2020-09-13 14:56:01                 0.0          0.000000          0.000000  

[38254 rows x 6 columns]```

Notice that I had to call `step1` and `step2` on the ColumnTransformer otherwise the naming of the column would look something like `cube__speed_cube` for the first step...
````

Comment: Try `verbose_feature_names_out=False`?

Comment: Okay, that was it! Thank you!